# No funciona el botón Start dentro del OnClick en un fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-button

Tengo el siguiente problema. No consigo que me funcione el botón "Start". En el XML lo tengo como clickable, pero aun así no me sale el toast dentro del OnClick. 
A continuación, les dejo el código dentro de la clase de mi fragmento:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_info_extremo2, container, false);
        EditText back=null;
        context=  vista.getContext();

        btsStart = vista.findViewById(R.id.buttonStartSeleccionProgramaExtremo);

        btsStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context,"Pulsando start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return vista;

    }
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: El botón buttonStartSeleccionProgramaExtremo no existe en fragment_fragment_info_extremo2.xml esa es la razón por la que no funciona el clic.

Answer (score 0):

Para que funcione el evento lo tienes que crear una vez ya se ha generado el botón en la vista de la forma que estas implementando estas asignando el evento a un objeto que aun no ha sido creado. Te dejo como debería ser con el código un poco mas limpio.

Ademas el contexto no necesitas guardarlo en una variable ya que puedes acceder a él desde el fragment ya que el fragment viene del activity, es una practica muy desaconsejada guardar el contexto ya que gasta muchos recursos.

```
EditText back=null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_info_extremo2, container, false);
    return vista;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);

    btsStart = getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonStartSeleccionProgramaExtremo);
    btsStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Pulsando start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tiene sentido que tenga que ser una vez creada la actividad. Pero aun asi sigue sin aparecer el toast. Gracias por la advertencia de no guardar el contexto.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es correcto, pero si no funciona el clic la única causa es que la referencia del botón con id `buttonStartSeleccionProgramaExtremo`:

```
 btsStart = vista.findViewById(R.id.buttonStartSeleccionProgramaExtremo);
```

no se encuentra en el layout que carga el `Fragment` que es `fragment_fragment_info_extremo2.xml`

```
vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_info_extremo2, container, false);
```

**El botón existe en un layout de tu proyecto pero no en el que carga el Fragment por esa razón puede no funciona el listener para el clic.**

---

Otra causa es simplemente que tu aplicación no permite mostrar notificaciones, esto incluye "Toast"s, verifica en la configuración que no este activado el bloqueo de notificaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorgersys,
el boton si esta dentro de ese fragment y el cargado es ese tambien. He revisado y el id tambien es correcto..

Comment: Ok si se encuentra dentro de fragment_fragment_info_extremo2.xml revisa que no se encuentre en otro layout, lo que sucede es que si se encuentra otro elemento "buttonStartSeleccionProgramaExtremo" en otro layout, puede estar tomando esa referencia. Revisa y me cometas @dansan

Comment: El unico boton con ese id en todo el proyecto es ese
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @Jorgesys

Comment: @dansan me parece que es configuración, agrega un toast al iniciar onCreateView() : Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"primer Toast...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       y dime si se muestra sin problema. Si no se muestra entonces es la configuración, revisa mi actualización, saludos.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo en el simulador de android studio. Si es verdad que no me muestra los toast.
En el main tengo varios botones que abren distintos fragments. desde aqui tampoco me muestra los toast. Sin embargo he puesto como prueba que al hacer click en start me abriese otro de los fragments pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Para ser mas exactos: En el main activity tengo varios botones y un Framelayout. Al hacer click en los botones se cargan los distintos fragments a un lado, pero siempre con los botones presentes. El problema es cuando dentro de uno de esos fragments quiero hacer el onclick